# android: set "INVISIBLE" to TextView but it is still showing

Tags: android, android-layout

I set "INVISIBLE" to TextView but it is still showing.

So i tried to resolve it  by some.

defined Variable using my code :

1. findPasswordText : Textview which i want hide
2. findPasswordContainer : Parent of textview
3. mainViewGroup : Root ViewGroup defined in xml

First.

change "VISIBLE" to "GONE"

ex :

```
private void hideFindPassword() {
    this.findPasswordContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.mainViewGroup.requestLayout();
}
```

Second.

Directly set "INVISIBLE" to textview.

ex:

```
private void hideFindPassword() {
    this.findPasswordText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    this.mainViewGroup.requestLayout();
}
```

Third.

set "INVISIBLE or GONE" to both.

```
private void hideFindPassword() {
    this.findPasswordContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.findPasswordText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    this.mainViewGroup.requestLayout();
}
```

Nothing resolve my problem.

so i need your help.

I attach images captured from actually display and xml code

1. Image : before set "INVISIBLE"

[image]

2. Image : after set "INVISIBLE"

[image]

3. Xml file

   ```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:id="@+id/find_password_container">
       <View
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="15dp"/>
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/label_find_password"
           android:textColor="#b6bec1"
           android:gravity="right"
           android:textSize="@dimen/base_font_size"
           android:id="@+id/find_password_button"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <View
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="15dp"/>
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/div_layout_for_third_part">
       <View
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="1dp"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:background="@color/colorNormal" />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:background="#ffffff"
           android:paddingLeft="5dp"
           android:paddingRight="5dp"
           android:text="@string/label_or" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Comment: follow tutorial here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/DemonstratesmakingaviewVISIBLEINVISIBLEandGONE.htm

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to simply set visibility of TextView to invisible in XML?

Answer (score 0):

you can directly set it through xml..

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

add this attribute either to your textview or linearlayout & programatically change it at run time depending upon your need

```
this.findPasswordContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

this.findPasswordText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

by using above line.

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/find_password_container">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_find_password"
        android:textColor="#b6bec1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="@dimen/base_font_size"
        android:id="@+id/find_password_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/div_layout_for_third_part">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/colorNormal" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/label_or" />
</RelativeLayout>
android android-layout
```

bu default the view will be gone, say you want it back at some point call

```
this.findPasswordText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

If that helped, dont forget to mark it UP.